# Why does xcode not see my app-bridge-header and tells me the file GIDSignInDelegate is undeclared?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm following this tutorial for using google sign in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?configured=true&ver=swift on my ios app.

I created a simple `app-Bridge-Header.h` file and put it in the main folder of my project.

Later on I added `GIDSignInDelegate` to the class `AppDelegate.swift`, but I'm getting the following exception:

[image]

`Use of undeclared type GIDSignInDelegate`. My app-Bridge-Header.h contains only one line:

```
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
```

I also did everything mentioned earlier in the tutorial. So why does xcode not see the specific import?

Comment: I think you still need to do `import Google` (or whatever your framework is called) at the top (near the import UIKit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to configure the path to your bridging header in the project settings.

[image]

For the new error, you need to implement the functions to make `AppDelegate` conform to `GIDSignInDelegate`:

> ```
> signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> signIn:didDisconnectWithUser:withError:
> ```

So just start typing `signIn` underneath the `didFinishLaunching` method and add both methods to the class.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice, but now I'm getting this error http://i.imgur.com/ufNrQ6o.png and build is still failing... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That just means that you haven't implemented the required `GIDSignInDelegate` functions in your `AppDelegate`. I'll edit my answer with what you need to add.

Comment: @xoudini could you walk me through it in a bit more detail? Sorry, I'm just getting started with swift and don't follow.